# Change left/right balance on playing audio in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I know the html5 audio stuff is all very new, but is there a way to change the left/right balance on a sound?

Something like this:

```
var snd = new Audio("test.mp3");
snd.balance = -1; // only left
snd.play();
```

Comment: It seemes, that channel balance isn't supported at all in html audio tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### As of 2021, this is possible using the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API). [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63193575/13331155) for more info.

---

*Original answer:*

Currently, this is not supported.

You can check the w3c spec for supported properties and methods. Note that browsers often provide more / less or different things. But in this case: no browser supports audio balance changes.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#audio

Answer (score 12):

#### This is possible using Audio Web API

The `<audio>` element is a very basic tool that allows you only the play/pause the playback and change the volume. If you need more complex operations you will need to use **Audio Web API**

The way Audio Web API works is by building a graph/chain of nodes linked together. On one side you have your audio source - which can be an audio file or some audio waves generated by you. On the other side, you have your audio destination (audio sink) which will be your computer speakers/headphones. In the middle, you can put as many nodes as you want for manipulating the audio. For example, you can use the `GainNode` to control the audio volume or you can use the `SterioPannerNode` to control the left and right balance.

The API is very complex, but to just control the Left/Right balance is very simple:

#### Step 1 - Load audio source

First, let's create an `<audio>` element so we can load the sound. You **don't** have to use the `<audio>` element if you load your audio via XHR request, or if you generate the sound at runtime.

```
<audio src="myCoolTrack.mp3"></audio>
```

#### Step 2 - Audio Context

Let's create an `AudioContext` and load the audio from the element to the context object

```
// for legacy browsers
const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

const audioContext = new AudioContext();

// get the audio element
const audioElement = document.querySelector('audio');

// pass it into the audio context
const track = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
```

#### Step 3 Stereo Node

Let's create a `StereoPannerNode` which will control the balance

```
// default pan set to 0 - center
const stereoNode = new StereoPannerNode(audioContext, { pan: 0 });

// change the value of the balance by updating the pan value
stereoNode.pan.value = -1; // left
stereoNode.pan.value = 0; // center
stereoNode.pan.value = 1; // right
```

#### Final Step

Connect all the nodes to a single graph/chain. With the input node (audio source) and the output node (speaker/ headphones). You can add more nodes in the middle for other audio manipulations, like volume, filtering etc.

```
track.connect(stereoNode).connect(audioContext.destination);
```

#### Additional reading

- Full API: [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API)
- Tutorial on how to create a "boombox" with volume and stereo controls: [Using Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Using_Web_Audio_API).
- Or you see a working demo here: [DEMO](https://codepen.io/Rumyra/pen/qyMzqN/).

#### Additional example

This answer uses the `StereoPannerNode` which controls the balance in a single `AudioNode`. But if you want to split your audio and manipulate each channel (left/right) separately, you will need to `ChannelSplitterNode` and `ChannelMergerNode`. You can find a full example on how to use them here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63272648/2658683