# how to balance audio in html5

Tags: html, audio

is it possible to manage audio channels balance in html5 using Javascript?

```
<audio id="audio_left" preload="auto">
    <source src="audio/audio_left.ogg" type="audio/ogg"></source>
    <source src="audio/audio_left.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></source>
</audio>
```

Comment: I don't think you can adjust the balance of audio in HTML5: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123844/change-left-right-balance-on-playing-audio-in-javascript

Comment: see if this helps http://terrillthompson.com/blog/32

Comment: Doesn't look like there is a property in the current html5 spec.  It is on a lot of wish lists, but your best bet will probably be setting the mix and balance in the mp3 file itself

Comment: yes i know hot to balance audio files, but i want to manage mono audio files

Comment: Any updates on this since '12?

Comment: No, the only way is web audio api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, no, as the Media API only provides high-level access to media files. There are a number of other APIs being developed, such as Mozilla's [Audio Data API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API) which provides more low-level stuff, but even that currently doesn't seem to support what you want. The [Web Audio API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html) provides a lot more, but again is still being developed.